# Scanimage can't get argument from variable

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to make a script for scanning and passing parameters using variables, but when I select a source it gives

> scanimage: setting of option --source failed (Invalid argument)

Here is a script example

```
#!/bin/bash
Source='--source="ADF Duplex"'
Device="canon_dr:libusb:001:011"
 scanimage -d $Device $Source > test.tiff
```

But if I run it just like, the script works

```
#!/bin/bash
Device="canon_dr:libusb:001:011"
 scanimage -d $Device --source="ADF Duplex" > test.tiff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell does interpolation and word splitting before passing your commands to programs it starts - that's why you needed `"ADF Duplex"` inside double quotes in Terminal, otherwise your program would have received `--source=ADF` followed by another parameter `Duplex`.

You need to do the same in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
Source="ADF Duplex"
Device="canon_dr:libusb:001:011"
scanimage -d $Device --source="$Source" > test.tiff
```

---

If you put this `--source="ADF Duplex"` in your `bash` variable, `scanimage` will *"see"* the double quotes and not know what to do with them.

If you insist on having `--source` in your `bash` variable, remove the double quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
Source='--source=ADF Duplex'
Device="canon_dr:libusb:001:011"
scanimage -d $Device $Source > test.tiff
```

Comment: Double qoutes around `$Source` did a trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
Source="--source=ADF Duplex"
```

No need for additional quotes around ADF Duplex.

```
Device="canon_dr:libusb:001:011"
scanimage -d "$Device" $Source > test.tiff
```

Ensure quotes around $Device to handle spaces if any

or try
`Source="--source='ADF Duplex'"`

or try

```
Source="--source=\"ADF Duplex\""
Device="canon_dr:libusb:001:011"
scanimage -d "$Device" $Source > test.tiff
```

or try

```
Source=(--source="ADF Duplex")
Device="canon_dr:libusb:001:011"
scanimage -d "$Device" "${Source[@]}" > test.tiff
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work either

Comment: what error do you see?

Comment: Can I see the console output?

Comment: What environment are you in?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in my case double qoutes needs to be around `$Source`